# Ubuntu - 12.04 - MySql won't start by using service mysql start

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

The only way I was able to get MySql to start was to issue:

> mysqld

When I issued this command, it started rolling back some database transactions that were conflicted.  I have tried issuing

> service mysql stop

and all I get is

> Unknown instance:

Now when I try to upload anything to WordPress I get a HTTP 500 error.  I am assuming this is because MySQL is running under a different user.  Any thoughts on how to get this working again?

Comment: Who are you logged in to the server as? And what kind of server? Generally you'd want to add a "d" to the second command you wrote. So "service mysqld stop"

Comment: I am logged in as the 'root' user.  This is an Ubuntu server.  I have always used 'service mysql start'/'service mysql stop' to stop/restart mysql

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense for Ubuntu. What does "service mysql status"  output? If nothing, try /etc/init.d/mysql status

Comment: 'service mysql status' gives me 'mysql stop/waiting'

Comment: BTW, it might be more productive to ask on http://askubuntu.com/  This isn't exactly a programming question, it is an ubuntu specific system administration question.

Comment: Is there a way to move this question over to askubuntu.com?

Answer (score 20):

MySql does not start when disk space is full, and does not give a detailed error message.
To check the free space on the server run:

```
 df -h /
```

Answer (score 18):

try

```
mysqld --verbose
```

for more details

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, @razlebe. Can't give more help here. Cheers

Comment: This was very helpful to diagnose the problem I was having, upvoted!

Answer (score 8):

`service mysql stop` will only work if mysql was started by one of the service start methods, such as `service mysql start` or `start mysql`, or `/etc/init.d/mysqld start`.  If you start mysql by launching the daemon directly without using upstart or init.d, then that is why you get the "unknown instance" error.  Of course, all of those valid options probably need to be prefixed with `sudo` if you aren't logged in as root.

Before worrying about the wordpress 500 error, I would first make sure that mysql is started correctly.  If it is still running stop it with the `kill` command.  Then, try `sudo service mysql start`.  Then, use `ps -ef` to see if mysql is running.  If not, check the mysql log files (**EDIT**: also check dmesg).  If it is running, try to connect to it with the the `mysql` command and the credentials in your wordpress `config.php` file.  If that doesn't work, figure out what is wrong there.  If it does work, then check the wordpress (really apache most likely), log file.

See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/125686/mysql-fails-to-start-after-upgrade-installation-etc

Comment: So, how do you stop mysqld?  I am unable to find the right command for this.

Comment: So I killed the process and tried starting it like you suggested and I get 'start: Job failed to start'.  there is nothing in the log file directory

Comment: From dmesg:  'init: mysql pre-start process (2257) terminated with status 1'

Comment: My best guess is that there is a problem with your my.cnf.  BTW, if you look at /etc/init/mysql.conf, you can see the pre-start section, and try executing it step by step.

Answer (score 2):

I know the thread is old but I found it when trying to find a solution to the same problem. Just want to add my 5 cents. It may help someone else.

After hunting for and trying various solutions, without the drastic uninstall and purge, my solution was ridiculously simple.

My disk was full! I can't believe I didn't check that first. Cleared it out and hey presto!

Comment: This is a duplicate of Dave Horner's comment above, but with less info.

Answer (score 0):

I had these exact symptoms on Ubuntu 14.04. The mysql --verbose trick yielded "Killed". I ran a dmesg which showed Out Of Memory. So I guess this can be caused by any system resource shortage. I also had nothing in the logs. I increased the memory in the machine and mysql started first time!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with  MY-SQL   on  Ubuntu-14.04.
I fixed the issue by commenting configuration in /etc/mysql/my.cnf  file.

> innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G
>
> innodb_log_file_size=54M

After commenting mysql service runs well..

Note :- If you comment these configuration then default configuration will take care the size of buffer pool and log file.
So not any issue .
But if you want to mention it manually , then provide 80% of your physical memory to buffer pool size.
and 25% of buffer pool size to log file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are logged in as a user with the privileges to restart mysql. I always use the root user.