# Cannot restart mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I got `Error establishing a database connection` for my WordPress website hosted by DigitalOcean. So I checked what's wrong with the database.

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart` returns

```
stop: Unknown instance: 
start: Job failed to start
```

`df -h /` returns the follows, so the disk is not full?

```
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-label/DOROOT   20G   12G  6.9G  63% /
```

`sudo -u mysql mysqld` returns

```
170828  4:33:48 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
170828  4:33:48 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.52-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 18825 ...
```

`mysqld` returns

```
170828  4:34:17 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
170828  4:34:17 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.52-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 18866 ...
170828  4:34:17 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/chengtie.lower-test
170828  4:34:17 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/chengtie.lower-test
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 13)
170828  4:34:17 [ERROR] Aborting

170828  4:34:17 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

So does anyone know what's wrong with mysql? How could I restart it?

**Edit 1:** I notice that I don't have `config.inc.php` or `config.sample.inc.php` under `/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin`.

Comment: Also make sure, `wp-config.php` has correct db credentials.

Comment: Try check apparmor settings, see here for details https://askubuntu.com/questions/75059/mysqld-gives-errcode13-because-it-cant-create-test-files

Comment: `wp-config.php` looks good, though there is `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');` (I don't know why `localhost` is used).

Comment: It seems there is issue with /var/lib/mysql/ https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/106135 may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is permission issue with /var/lib/mysql/

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/106135 may solve it.

Comment: Just `sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/mysql` did the job, several minutes later, I could `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`, and the website was operational again. Actually I never changed this permission manually by myself, but I did `apt-get upgrade` which might be the evil.

Comment: The `Error establishing a database connection` occurred once again, this side `sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/mysql` + `apt-get upgrade` solved the issue... really odd...

Answer (score 1):

Did you looked at this post : [Ubuntu - 12.04 - MySql won't start by using service mysql start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138911/ubuntu-12-04-mysql-wont-start-by-using-service-mysql-start)

You can try

```
mysqld --verbose
```

to get more information

Comment: `mysqld --verbose` returns the same message as `mysqld`.

Comment: @SoftTimur I think this should help you. https://askubuntu.com/questions/75059/mysqld-gives-errcode13-because-it-cant-create-test-files

Answer (score 1):

> mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 13)

That is "permissions".  I suspect MySQL was installed as some user other than root.  Suggest you reinstall (as root), especially if you don't have any data yet.

Comment: I have some photos and texts in the WordPress website, are they stored in mysql? If so, how could I keep them?

Comment: Re-installing mysql was not necessary, just changing its permission solved the problem.

Comment: Let's hope that was the only file or directory that needed the permissions changed.

Answer (score 0):

`define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');` should not be 'localhost', it should the mysql server hostname.

Comment: Where can I find this `mysql server hostname`?

Comment: It'll be provided to you by your webhost. DigitalOcean can help you find it